# initialize Croppie for uploading and cropping image

Tags: javascript, croppie

i want t use Croppie for uploading and cropping image. 
https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/
I have added croppie.css and croppie.js to my files. I want to add Croppie in a overlay page, here is the code for this:

```
overLayPage(){
// overlay--active
$("body").append(`
  <div class="overlay" id="image-editor-overlay">
  </div>
  `);
}
```

Then in the constructor, i use these codes to initialize Croppie.

```
constructor() {

this.overLayPage();

var c = new Croppie(document.getElementById('item'), '#image-editor-overlay' );
c.method(args);

this.body = $("#image-editor-overlay");

this.events();
  }
```

After compiling, i'm facing with this error. (sorry i dont know why the screenshot is in a link).

[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrcXJ.png)

Thank you very much. I am very new in javascript.

Comment: I suspect that there is no element on your page that has `item` as its ID when the constructor is called (did you mean to bind it to the overlay element?). Also, you should be giving croppie an options object for the second parameter, not a string.

Comment: @CRice Thank you very much for your help. I just found out that i use 'viewport' or 'canvas' in the second parameter, but for the "item" . i dont know what i should write instead of it. I see it in its documentation

Comment: I have written a post for helping people to use croppie.js 
May be this will help anyone in future:
https://shaktisinghcheema.com/image-upload-with-cropping/